# How to read nested dictionary from csv in Julia

Tags: csv, dictionary, julia

I want to read a nested dictionary with 5 levels from a csv file in Julia. I have the Python code for it, but I don't know how to do it in Julia. Can someone help?                          '

```py
demand = {}
with open("demand.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data_file.readline()
    for row in data_file:
        row = row.strip().split(",")
        demand.setdefault(row[0],{}).setdefault(row[1],{}).setdefault(row[2],{}).setdefault(row[3],{})[row[4]] = (row[5])
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What specific issues are you facing?

Comment: Check Discourse at: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/best-way-of-building-a-heavily-nested-dict/14139

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a recursive Dict constructor. Here is one that, unlike the Python example, works with arbitrary numbers of columns >= 2:

```
function makeifnone(dict::Dict, list::Vector)
    if length(list) < 2
        throw("List depth too shallow to get a key=>value pair in makeifnone()")
    elseif length(list) == 2
        dict[list[1]] = list[2]
    else
        k = popfirst!(list)
        if !haskey(dict, k)
            dict[k] = Dict()
        end
        makeifnone(dict[k], list)
    end
end

demand = Dict()

open("demand.csv", "r") do data_file
    readline(data_file)
    rows = readlines(data_file)
    for row in rows
        entries = split(strip(row), ",")
        makeifnone(demand, entries)       
    end
    println(demand)
end
```

I don't have your csv, but with this csv file:

```
Name,Birthdate,State,Relation,Email,Notes
Sally Whittaker,1988-12-05,Illinois,friend,sally@mail.com,student
Belinda Jameson,1994-02-17,California,family,beljames@example.com,cousin
Jeff Bragg,2018-10-10,Texas,family,jb@texas.edu,brother-in-law
Sandy Allen,2002-03-09,Colorado,friend,sandya@mail.com,ex
Fred Kobo,1967-10-10,Colorado,friend,fkobo@example.net,brother to Belinda
Nate Smith,1983-04-22,Colorado,family,nate.smith@mail.com,nephew
```

I get the same result as with Python, though the Python version prints without the type notations.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Since in my case the values are supposed to be integers, I added parse() in the makeifnone() function.